# If $A$ is a closed set that contains every rational number $r\in [0,1]$, show that $[0,1]\subset A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $A$ is a closed set that contains every rational number $r\in [0,1]$, show that $[0,1]\subset A$

What I did:

Suppose that $[0,1] \not\subset A$. Then there exists a irrational number (all rationals of $[0,1]$ are by definition in $A$) $r_1$ such that $r_1\notin A$, that is, $r_1\in ext(A)$. Since $A$ is closed, its exterior is open, therefore there exists a ball around $r_1$ such that this ball does not intersect with $A$. But every open ball around an irrational should contain a rational. Therefore we showed that, for example, $\sqrt{2}/2$ is irrational. Suppose it isn't in $A$, then there is an open ball such that $B(sqrt{2}/2)$ is not in $A$. That means that rationals very close to it are not in $A$, but they should.

I'm having trouble in this last part: saying that rationals very close to it should be on $A$ but they're not

Comment: Do you have  a theorem from your class, or from your book that says whenever $\alpha < \beta$ are real numbers, there exists a rational number $q$ such that $\alpha < q < \beta$?

Comment: Essentially this depends upon the definition of $\Bbb R,$ from which it is shown that a non-empty open interval of $\Bbb R$  cannot be disjoint from $\Bbb Q.$... The ordered field $\Bbb R$ can be extended to a larger ordered field that does not have this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is closed, its exterior is open, so there exists a ball around $r_1$ such that this ball does not intersect $A$. But then $A$ contains the rationals, and we know that we can find a rational number in any ball around any irrational number. Therefore, $A$ must intersect this ball, which is a contradiction.

Or, what you were trying to attempt with $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ seems to be a contrapositive. You then seemed to be trying to prove that if $[0,1] \not\subset A $ then $A$ does not contain all the rationals. This is also true by the argument you gave : If say $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ were not in $A$ ,  then some ball around $\sqrt{2} \over 2$ s not in $A$, but this this ball contains some rational so that rational is not in $A$. This proves (modulo the fact that instead of $\sqrt 2 \over 2$ you should take an element specified by non-containment of $[0,1]$ in A) the contrapositive statement (which is equivalent to the usual statement, and therefore also qualifies as a proof).

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that the rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$? This together with the implication $A\subseteq B \implies \overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$ (bar denotes closure) suffices. We just have that $$\Bbb Q \cap [0,1] \subseteq A  \implies [0,1]=\overline{\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]}\subseteq \overline{A} =A.$$